# Laravel view page not generating, its Blank Page

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

Does anyone, Know Laravel, one of our old project was developed in Laravel 5.5. we made a copy of the website in the new host, but the website is displaying a blank page, I checked the controller file before sending the view page data line. the data is displayed when I print it in the controller but the view is not. I checked the view under the Storage/Framework/views here its not generate anything, I think the view compiler is not running properly. please help me to resolve the problem.PHP : 7.3 , Laravel 5.5
There is no error display,
Debugging error is also not displayed.

Comment: Please show your relevant code. It is difficult to tell what the issue it without more info.

Comment: Please check the error log for both your web server and in `storage/logs`. A white screen is often an Internal Server Error, and the logs should provide more information.